# "Abandoned" as an antonym of "Abstemious" (adj) ?

Tags: vocabulary

Can we use  "Abandoned" as an antonym of "Abstemious" (adj)?

Please explain your answer.

Comment: Notwithstanding the answers below, I don't think this is a common usage for "abandoned".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while to wrap my brain around your question, but I think I've got it now, and the answer is "yes, but".

[abandoned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abandoned?show=0&t=1291130697): 1. wholly free from restraint 2. given up; forsaken

[abstemious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstemious): marked by restraint especially in the consumption of food or alcohol

So, if you're using *abandoned* in the "wholly free from restraint" sense, then yes, it seems like a perfect antonym for abstemious. The ***but*** comes from the fact that most people would probably interpret *abandoned* as the past tense of *abandon*, in which sense it has nothing to do with restraint or lack thereof. Without sufficient context, using it as an antonym for "abstemious" could lead to much head-scratching.

A much better antonym for *abstemious* is *gluttonous*.

Comment: `A much better antonym for abstemious is gluttonous` or simply may be 'wild' or 'unreserved'!

Comment: 'glutton' is referred to a person who loves food, so I guess 'gluttonous' is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Yep!

[Abstemious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abstemious?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) means moderate in appetite, restrained, characterized by abstinence, etc. [Abandoned](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abandoned?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) can mean unrestrained and uncontrolled. These are pretty opposite from each other.